# StringBuilder - find last index of a character

Tags: c#, .net

I'd like to find a specific last character in a `StringBuilder`.
I know, I can solve it with `while()` but is there an build it option to do that easily?

eg:

```
private static StringBuilder mySb = new StringBuilder("");
mySb.Add("This is a test[n] I like Orange juice[n] Can you give me some?");
```

Now: It shoud find the `]` and give me the possition. Like: 40

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate, have you checked this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12261344/fastest-search-method-in-stringbuilder ?

Comment: Let me be clear. Do you need to get the last index of `]` ??  Please have a look [StringBuilder Extensions](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/129369/StringBuilder-Extensions) you will find everything you need!!

Comment: You could call `ToString` on the `StringBuilder` and then use `LastIndexOf` on that `string`...

Comment: fyi, the index would be 39 since its 0 indexed.

Comment: Why can't you check the string _before_ appending it to the stringbuilder?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Convert the `StringBuilder` to a string with the `toString` method, thereafter you can make use of the `LastIndexOf` method.

```
mySb.ToString().LastIndexOf(']');
```

[LastIndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.lastindexof%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Reports the zero-based index position of the last occurrence of a
>   specified Unicode character or string within this instance. The method
>   returns -1 if the character or string is not found in this instance.
>
> This member is overloaded. For complete information about this member,
>   including syntax, usage, and examples, click a name in the overload
>   list.

Comment: Yes, you can. But if you'll do this in a loop you will always create a new string from the complete `StringBuilder` just to find an index. This can be quite inefficient. I would suggest to create methods/extensions that use a loop on the `StringBuilder` itself.

Answer (score 5):

Since there is no builtin method and always creating a `string` from the `StringBuilder` via `ToString` can be quite inefficient you could create an extension method for this purpose:

```
public static int LastIndexOf(this StringBuilder sb, char find, bool ignoreCase = false, int startIndex = -1, CultureInfo culture = null)
{
    if (sb == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(sb));
    if (startIndex == -1) startIndex = sb.Length - 1;
    if (startIndex < 0 || startIndex >= sb.Length) throw new ArgumentException("startIndex must be between 0 and sb.Lengh-1", nameof(sb));
    if (culture == null) culture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

    int lastIndex = -1;
    if (ignoreCase) find = Char.ToUpper(find, culture);
    for (int i = startIndex; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        char c = ignoreCase ? Char.ToUpper(sb[i], culture) : (sb[i]);
        if (find == c)
        {
            lastIndex = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return lastIndex;
}
```

Add it to a static, accessible (extension) class, then you can use it in this way:

```
StringBuilder mySb = new StringBuilder("");
mySb.Append("This is a test[n] I like Orange juice[n] Can you give me some?");
int lastIndex = mySb.LastIndexOf(']');  // 39
```

Comment: Always using the current culture for the case insensitive comparison might not be a good idea. Turkish `i` vs `ı` etc.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: i have edited my answer, have a look. I think it's sufficient to use a `bool` as parameter when comparing chars, isn't it?

Comment: I generally prefer passing in a `CultureInfo` or simply using the invariant culture everywhere, but locale aware string functions are a mess in .net. No idea why they used the current local by default.