# Performing actions on a string using a StringBuilder

Tags: c#, .net, string, search, stringbuilder

I am coding a `C#` application that appends, inserts, replaces and finds `string` content in `string` called content. Multiple objects called `editObjects` are performing these actions on the same `string` called content.

I am currently passing a `StringBuilder` object to each `editObject` object, and then each `editObject` performs the actions on the `StringBuilder` object.

This question has two parts:

Am I correct in saying that a `StringBuilder` is the most efficient way to perform multiple actions on a `string`?

I have found this post from 2013: [Fastest search method in StringBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12261344/fastest-search-method-in-stringbuilder), and would like to know if there is some known code that is a more efficient way to find the index of a `string` in a `StringBuilder`?

```
public static class StringBuilderSearching
{
  public static bool Contains(this StringBuilder haystack, string needle)
  {
    return haystack.IndexOf(needle) != -1;
  }
  public static int IndexOf(this StringBuilder haystack, string needle)
  {
    if(haystack == null || needle == null)
      throw new ArgumentNullException();
    if(needle.Length == 0)
      return 0;//empty strings are everywhere!
    if(needle.Length == 1)//can't beat just spinning through for it
    {
      char c = needle[0];
      for(int idx = 0; idx != haystack.Length; ++idx)
        if(haystack[idx] == c)
          return idx;
      return -1;
    }
    int m = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int[] T = KMPTable(needle);
    while(m + i < haystack.Length)
    {
      if(needle[i] == haystack[m + i])
      {
        if(i == needle.Length - 1)
          return m == needle.Length ? -1 : m;//match -1 = failure to find conventional in .NET
        ++i;
      }
      else
      {
        m = m + i - T[i];
        i = T[i] > -1 ? T[i] : 0;
      }
    }
    return -1;
  }      
  private static int[] KMPTable(string sought)
  {
    int[] table = new int[sought.Length];
    int pos = 2;
    int cnd = 0;
    table[0] = -1;
    table[1] = 0;
    while(pos < table.Length)
      if(sought[pos - 1] == sought[cnd])
        table[pos++] = ++cnd;
      else if(cnd > 0)
        cnd = table[cnd];
      else
        table[pos++] = 0;
    return table;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`StringBuilder` is faster [for most `string` manipulations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21644658/how-to-use-stringbuilder-wisely/21644889#21644889) - That doesn't mean it is the best ***for all*** *multiple actions* done on a `string`.

In your case, you are willing to find a `string` inside the `StringBuilder`, this requires you to do one of two things:

- Doing a standard search at *O(n)* iterating the whole `StringBuilder`, which can be done in a pretty optimized way like the code you have posted in the question.
- Indexing `chars` or `strings` on every addition and removal of data to/from the `StringBuilder`. Note that indexing means you will need to analyse every `string` you add or remove to/from the `StringBuilder` which creates a little overhead for each ***manipulation action***.

  - You need to do the judging of what your application does more and what will disturb your application more - *`O(n)`* search instead of an *`O(log(n))`* ***or*** *`O(n + m)`* manipulations instead of *`O(n)`* ones. <sub>*(Where `m` is the overhead for each insertion/removal divided by the average inserted/removed`string` length)*</sub>
  - Basic indexing illustration:

  [image: string indexing]

  - Indexes which are in between are fine too for balance (maximum 2 `chars` index/maximum 3 `chars`/etc...).