# Remove matching string from StringBuilder

Tags: vb.net, stringbuilder

How can I remove a certain `string` on a `StringBuilder`? Ex. `.append("Stack over flow dot com")` Remove `flow` and `.toString()` is now equal to `Stack over dot com`. I want to try `.remove()` but it only accepts `(startIndex, length)`. Do I have to search for the string first in the `StringBuilder` and store index and length to be used for `.remove(i,x)`? If possible, is there a better way to do it?

```
Dim someStrBlr As New StringBuilder 
Dim someStrRmv = "flow"
Dim someString = "Stack over flow dot com"
someStrBlr.append(someString)
someStrBlr.remove(?) 'remove? "flow"
someStrBlr.remove(?) 'replace? "flow" with ""
Console.WriteLine(someStrBlr.toString()) "Stack over dot com"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below

```
Dim someStrBlr As New StringBuilder
Dim someStrRmv = "flow"
Dim someString = "Stack over flow dot com"
someStrBlr.Append(someString)
someStrBlr.Replace(someStrRmv, "") 'removes the flow from string
Console.WriteLine(someStrBlr.ToString()) '"Stack over dot com"
```

By the way, if you really want to find and then remove, refer the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12261344/fastest-search-method-in-stringbuilder)

Comment: I knew it!, I thought `.Replace()` only accepts `char`. I was about to answer my own question, but thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Dim someStrBlr As New StringBuilder  
 Dim someStrRmv = "flow" 
 Dim someString = "Stack over flow dot com" 
 someStrBlr.append(someString)
 someStrBlr.replace(someStrRmv,"") ' Replace with empty string
 Console.WriteLine(someStrBlr.toString())
```

Ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3h5afh4w(v=vs.110).aspx